# Asking for input multiple times within a while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

```
quit_game = "Goodbye, thank you for playing."

while True:
    tell_joke = print("Pete, Pete and Repeat went out on the lake in their boat. Pete and Pete fell out. Who is left in the boat? ")
    if input() == "REpeat":
        print(tell_joke)
        break
    elif input() == "Quit":
        print(quit_game)
    break;
```

I'm needing to loop back to the original "tell_joke" statement each time the user enters "REpeat" however it either prints the new defined input or reads off as none.

Comment: You need to get the input once and use that in the if statements

Comment: You shouldn't "break" if you want to repeat. I guess you want "continue".

Answer (score 0):

In your `while` loop the `break` statement after the `elif` will be always executed, so your loop will run only one time. To avoid that, you can simply put the `break` inside the `elif` statement; speaking of `break`s, if you want to repeat the cycle each time a `"REpeat"` is taken from input, then you want to delete the `break` inside the `if` statement. Besides, the input, in your code, is taken two times: a first time `input()` is called to check the `if` condition and another time to check the `elif` one. To avoid that, the first thing to do in your loop will be to save the user input into a variable.

Moreover, be careful, 'cause you're calling two times per cycle (when input `"REpeat"`) the `print()` function and assigning its return value to `tell_joke` and, after that, you're calling again the `print()` function to print the `tell_joke` variable, which contains the result of `print()`, which explains the "casual" `None` output. To prevent multiple useless assignment, if you don't plan to change the value of `tell_joke`, you can declare and assign it before the whole loop, alongside the `quit_game` string. Remember, just to be more clear, that with only those two `if` statements, you are not handling any other input from the user than `"REpeat"` and `"Quit"`, the loop will simply repeat itself.

If I correctly understand your desired output, it should look like this:

```py
quit_game = "Goodbye, thank you for playing."
tell_joke = "Pete, Pete and Repeat went out on the lake in their boat. Pete and Pete fell out. Who is left in the boat?"
while True:
    my_input = input()
    if my_input == "REpeat":
        print(tell_joke)
    elif my_input == "Quit":
        print(quit_game)
        break
```

If you want to know more on the control flow tools in python, I redirect you to their [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html).

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `continue` if you want to loop back in the loop and `break` only if you want to exit. In your `while` loop you have a `break` and hence it never loop backs. Below is the code which I think you want:

```
quit_game = "Goodbye, thank you for playing."
tell_joke = "Pete, Pete and Repeat went out on the lake in their boat. Pete and Pete fell out. Who is left in the boat?"
while True:
    option = input('What to do? 1. Repeat 2. Quit: ')
    if option.lower() == "repeat":
        print(tell_joke)
        continue
    elif option.lower() == "quit":
        print(quit_game)
        break
    else:
        print ("Invalid option provided..provide the right one")
```

Output:

```
What to do? 1. Repeat 2. Quit: bh
Invalid option provided..provide the right one
What to do? 1. Repeat 2. Quit: Repeat
Pete, Pete and Repeat went out on the lake in their boat. Pete and Pete fell out. Who is left in the boat?
What to do? 1. Repeat 2. Quit: Quit
Goodbye, thank you for playing.
```